# Proving that if $a+b$ and $ab$ are of the same parity, then $a$ and $b$ are even.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

Here is the proof:

> Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that if $a+b$ and $ab$ are of the same parity, then $a$ and $b$ are even.

When working these problems, I do try to set them up logically. My scratch work usually looks something like this:

> $P: a+b$ and $ab$ are the same parity
>
> $Q: a$ and $b$ are even
>
> $P \Rightarrow Q:$ If $a+b$ and $ab$ are the same parity, then $a$ and $b$ are even.
>
> $Q \Rightarrow P$: If $a$ and $b$ are even, then $a+b$ are the same parity.

For some reason, I am getting caught up on writing the contrapositive of this statement when addressing the forwards ($P \Rightarrow Q$) direction of this biconditional.

Here is what I was thinking:

> If $a$ or $b$ is not even (odd), then $a+b$ or $ab$ are of different parity.

I believe I am negating too much, and this is where I struggle: what would the proper negation look like? How do I know what to negate (or switch) vs. what I should leave alone? I generally get that "and" becomes an "or", but then I feel like I start to negate too much (if that makes sense...).

Any advice? I can usually get this far pretty easily, but I wanted to use contrapositive for $P \Rightarrow Q$, and I don't believe I am writing the statement correctly. In addition to verifying this, I would appreciate any advice when it comes to what portion of my statement I should negate. Thanks!

Comment: You have got it right. The contrapositive of $P \Rightarrow Q$ is $\neg Q \Rightarrow \neg P$

Comment: Have you tried proving this directly?

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow Yes-- but the book explicitly uses the contrapositive for the forward direction in it's "guided" solution, so I figured I'd try to work through it in a similar fashion.

Comment: I might say "then $a+b$ and $ab$ are of different parity" (using "and" rather than "or" in the English), but your formulation is essentially correct

Comment: @mia.avery In my answer, I tried to address two things: 1) How you could effectively negate your statements without complicating the matter too much, and 2) how to write up a fairly well-polished proof by contraposition. Hope you find it helpful in addition coldnumber's answer!

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow Thank you very much for your response. I am working through it all now. As mentioned in a comment for your answer, I also sometimes struggle with picking out the logical vs nonlogical ands/ors. ...yay...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The contrapositive of the statement

> If $\overbrace{\text{$ab$ and $a+b$ have the same parity}}^{\large P}$, then $\overbrace{\text{$a$ is even and $b$ is even}}^{\large Q}$.

is

> If $\overbrace{\text{$a$ is odd or $b$ is odd}}^{\large\lnot Q}$, then $\overbrace{\text{$ab$ and $a+b$ have different parities}}^{\large\lnot P}$.

Note that $Q$ is the conjunction $S\land T$, where $S$ means "$a$ is even" and $T$ means "$b$ is even". Thus, $\lnot Q$ is the disjunction $\lnot S\lor\lnot T$.

---

Here is an alternate approach:

$\begin{array}{cr}
\text{$ab$ and $a+b$ have the same parity}\\
\Updownarrow&\qquad\text{(1)}\\
\text{$ab-(a+b)$ is even}\\
\Updownarrow&\qquad\text{(2)}\\
\text{$(a-1)(b-1)$ is odd}\\
\Updownarrow&\qquad\text{(3)}\\
\text{$a-1$ is odd and $b-1$ is odd}\\
\Updownarrow&\qquad\text{(4)}\\
\text{$a$ is even and $b$ is even}\\
\end{array}$

Comments:
$(1)$: $m$ and $n$ have the same parity if and only if $m-n$ is even
$(2)$: $ab-(a+b)=(a-1)(b-1)-1$
$(3)$: $mn$ is odd if and only if both $m$ and $n$ are odd
$(4)$: $a-1$ has the opposite parity from $a$

Comment: Nice answer! Could be useful, I imagine, to `\tag` in order to show/explain/comment how you jump from one step to the next. I get it and appreciate its slickness, but I imagine one or more of the linkages may be somewhat difficult for OP to grasp (based on the phraseology of how the question was couched). Just a thought.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow: I thought it was pretty self-explanatory, but I've added some "tagged" comments.

Comment: @robjohn +1 Nice to see how you're designing a 'calculational' proof format that is so close to what Dijkstra/Scholten/etc. designed years ago; see [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html) for a summary.  Just now, I've added another answer, to show that format (and using slightly different laws so that no 'ad hoc' / 'slick' factoring is required).

Comment: Was just about to put my reasoning/solution on this site when I saw this.

Answer (score 3):

You have the contrapositive right. You must negate $P$ and $Q$ separately and prove that the negation of $Q$ implies the negation of $P$.

To expand on this, for "$a$ and $b$ are even" to be false, you only need one of $a$ and $b$ to be odd, so the negation is "$a$ is not even or $b$ is not even".

And for the statement "$a+b$ and $ab$ have the same parity" to be false, you need $a+b$ and $ab$ to have different parity, which is what you wrote.

(Something interesting about writing the proof of this direction by contrapositive is that you get to use a "without loss of generality", because the expressions $a+b$ and $ab$ are symmetric. If you were proving it directly, you'd have to treat two cases, one where both expressions are even, and one where both are odd.)

---

**EDIT:** Clarification of the and/or discussion in the comments.

I'll try to illustrate the difference between an *and* that is negated into an *or* and an *and* that isn't.

In the statement

> $a$ **and** $b$ are even

you have a logical *and*, which turns into an *or* in the negation:

> $a$ is odd **or** $b$ is odd

which can also be written as

> $a$ **or** $b$ is odd

The difference between this statement and yours is that this statement can actually be written as two statements connected by an *and*:

> $a$ is even **and** $b$ is even

If we let $E(x)$ be the statement "$x$ is even", then the whole statement above is $E(a) \land E(b)$, meaning its negation is $\lnot E(a)\lor \lnot E(b)$.

In contrast, we can't rewrite your statement ($a+b$ and $ab$ have the same parity) as two statements connected with an *and*,  because it makes no sense to say

> $a$ has the same parity **and** $b$ has the same parity

This happens because "$a$ and $b$ have the same parity" is a statement about **two** quantities, not two statements, each about one quantity, connected by an *and*.

---

Here is another (maybe simpler) example:

> Alice **and** Bob like pizza

Can be rewritten as

> Alice likes pizza **and** Bob likes pizza

So its negation is

> Alice **or** Bob doesn't like pizza

However, the statement

> Alice **and** Bob are friends

cannot be rewritten as

> Alice is friend **and** Bob is friend

so its negation is

> Alice and Bob are not friends

Basically you have to evaluate whether the statement you're trying to negate is a statement *relating* two quantities (in which case the *and* isn't negated into an *or*) or two individual statements, each about one quantity, connected by a logical *and* (which is negated into an *or*). I hope this clarifies things a little.

---

(A side note: In the cases where the *and* is not logical, it is also not essential to the meaning of the sentence.
We could rephrase your statement as  "$a+b$ has the same parity as $ab$"; then its negation is more clearly $a+b$ does not have the same parity as $ab$. Similarly,  we could rephrase the second example as "Alice is friends with Bob"; then its negation is "Alice is not friends with Bob". (This is a side note because it's trickier and it might be harder to generalize.))

Comment: Yeah, I think that is why the book suggested using contrapositive instead of direct. Sometimes contrapositive is easier, but if you misdefine it then you are totally hosed. Thanks for your help (again...). I can't wait for this final to be over with...

Comment: You still have to treat two cases, I believe, because you have to consider when *both* $a$ and $b$ are odd. But you are right that you get to take advantage of a nice little symmetric argument to facilitate the proof by contraposition.

Comment: She *doesn't* have it quite right.  She has negated "$p+q$ and $pq$ have the same parity" to "$p+q$ **or** $pq$ have the same parity", which does not even make sense.  This is not the logical "and", so it shouldn't be changed to "or", any more than the negation of "I went to Steak and Shake for lunch" is "I did not go to Steak or Shake for lunch".

Comment: @MYUSERNAMEISALIE That's actually one of the things I was worried about. I have a hard time piecing out the logical and's/or's from the nonlogical ones.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow Huh, yes, I hadn't noticed that. (But she could also show that $2k+1+b$ is odd if and only if $(2k+1)b$ is even, no? Admittedly this is uglier.)

Comment: @coldnumber I'm not sure why she would do that. I think a simple "it is not the case" negation is perfectly fine in this instance (and is easiest to deal with). It's kind of an annoying question though, to be honest--it's like you have to focus more on the mechanics of the proof than actually grappling with the concepts. Frustrating.

Comment: @MYUSERNAMEISALIE I completely read over that one. I would have thought it was just a grammar mistake. In general, the negation of the construction "x and y have the same z" is "x and y do not have the same z".

Answer (score 3):

> What would the proper negation look like?

It turns out that, in this case, there are a number of ways you can go in how you want to prove this claim, not just via direct proof or contrapositive but also how you frame the question logically as well. I'll outline what I think is the *clearest* and *easiest* way of going about it.

---

**Claim:** Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $a+b$ and $ab$ have the same parity, then $a$ and $b$ are even.

*Proof.* Begin by writing out the claim logically, as you have done before:

- $P : a+b$ and $ab$ have the same parity.
- $Q : a$ and $b$ are both even.

Hence, you are trying to prove that $P\to Q$, something you can prove by contraposition since $P\to Q\equiv\neg Q\to\neg P$. Hence, formulate the negations of $P$ and $Q$:

- $\neg P : a+b$ and $ab$ do not have the same parity (this is an easier formulation than trying to mess with some application of DeMorgan).
- $\neg Q : a$ or $b$ is odd (or both).

Thus, to prove $\neg Q\to\neg P$, you need to prove the following:

> If $a$ or $b$ are odd, then $a+b$ and $ab$ do not have the same parity.

Note that there are three cases to consider:

1. $a$ is odd and $b$ is even.
2. $a$ is even and $b$ is odd.
3. $a$ is odd and $b$ is odd.

As coldnumber pointed out, you can essentially "lump together" (1) and (2) due to symmetry (so called "without loss of generality"). So you ultimately need to consider, say, (1) and (3). I'll prove them below, and their proofs will conclude the overall proof.

**Proof of (1):** Let $a=2\ell+1, \ell\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b=2\eta, \eta\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have that 
$$
a+b=2\ell+1+2\eta=2(\ell+\eta)+1=2\gamma+1,\gamma\in\mathbb{Z}\tag{$a+b$ is odd}
$$
and
$$
ab=(2\ell+1)2\eta=2[\eta(2\ell+1)]=2\gamma, \gamma\in\mathbb{Z}.\tag{$ab$ is even}
$$
This proves (1). $\blacksquare$

**Proof of (3):** Let $a=2\ell+1, \ell\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b=2\eta+1, \eta\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have that
$$
a+b=(2\ell+1)+(2\eta+1)=2(\ell+\eta+1)=2\gamma, \gamma\in\mathbb{Z}\tag{$a+b$ is even}
$$
and
$$
ab=(2\ell+1)(2\eta+1)=4\ell\eta+2\ell+2\eta+1=2(2\ell\eta+\ell+\eta)+1=2\gamma+1, \gamma\in\mathbb{Z}.\tag{odd}
$$
This proves (3). $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

This answer is close to [robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn)'s answer, written in very similar 'calculational' style designed and used by Edsger W. Dijkstra, Carel S. Scholten, et al.: see [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html) for more details.$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\even}[1]{#1\text{ is even}}
$

We calculate as follows:
$$\calc
    a + b\text{ and }ab\text{ have the same parity}
\op\equiv\hint{definition of parity}
    \even{a + b} \;\equiv\; \even{ab}
\op\equiv\hint{LHS: either both or none are even; RHS: at least one is even}
    \even a  \;\equiv\; \even b \;\equiv\; \even a \lor \even b
\op\equiv\hint{logic: what Dijkstra et al. call the 'golden rule' $\ref{0}$}
    \even a \land \even b
\endcalc$$

Here the 'golden rule' is the following law of propositional logic:
$$
\tag{0}
P \land Q \;\equiv\; P \lor Q \;\equiv\; P \;\equiv\; Q
$$
Also note that logical equivalence $\;\equiv\;$ ("if and only if") is associative, so that no parentheses are necessary in that last statement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(X) = (X-a)(X-b) = X^2 - (a+b)X + ab$.

Since $f(X) \equiv X^2\pmod{2}$, it follows that its roots are even.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the parity tables.

**Addition** $+$
$$
\begin{array}{cc|cc|cc}
+ &   & a & a & b & b\\
  &   & o & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #008000]e & o & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #008000]e\\
\hline
a & o & e & o & e & o\\
a & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #008000]e & o & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #800000]e & o & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #800000]e\\
\hline
b & o & e & o & e & o\\
b & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #008000]e & o & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #800000]e & o & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #800000]e
\end{array}
$$

**Multiplication** $\cdot$
$$
\begin{array}{cc|cc|cc}
\cdot &   & a & a & b & b\\
      &   & o & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #008000]e & o & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #008000]e\\
\hline
a     & o & o & e & o & e\\
a     & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #008000]e & e & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #800000]e & e & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #800000]e\\
\hline
b     & o & o & e & o & e\\
b     & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #008000]e & e & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #800000]e & e & \bbox[4px,border:2px solid #800000]e
\end{array}
$$

Clearly both $a$ and $b$ are *even*.